# How to simplify a dataframe to signal if a level does or does not have a value in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, binary-data, data-preprocessing

I would like to reduce my dataframe so that I can determine if a checklist does or does not have a presence value (i.e., X) instead of a number. Each row in the current dataframe corresponds to an observation and the number of birds associated with that observation, and each checklist has multiple observations.

I have created an example to illustrate what my current dataframe looks like (`original_df`) and what I would like my dataframe to look like (`goal_df`).

```
checklist_id <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
obs_id <- c("obs1", "obs2", "obs3", "obs4", "obs5", "obs6", "obs7", "obs8", "obs9")
how_many_birds <- c('7','8','X','2','3','1','6','8','X')

original_df <- data.frame(checklist_id, obs_id, how_many_birds)

# checklist_id obs_id how_many_birds
# 1            1   obs1              7
# 2            1   obs2              8
# 3            2   obs3              X
# 4            2   obs4              2
# 5            2   obs5              3
# 6            3   obs6              1
# 7            3   obs7              6
# 8            3   obs8              8
# 9            3   obs9              X

checklist_id_goal <- c(1,2,3)
at_least_one_x <- c(0,1,1)

goal_df <- data.frame(checklist_id_goal, at_least_one_x)

#  checklist_id_goal at_least_one_x
#1                 1              0
#2                 2              1
#3                 3              1
```

Comment: Thank you J-J-J, you are so right! I got turned around and thought I was on stackoverflow but accidently ended up in stats.stackexchange.

Comment: it looks like someone answered your question, so problem solved anyway!

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a [filtering join](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter-joins.html)

```r
checklist_df = data.frame(checklist_id = c(1, 2, 3))
semi_join(checklist_df, 
          filter(original_df, how_many_birds == 'X'), 
          by = 'checklist_id')

##   checklist_id
## 1            2
## 2            3
```

Comment: Do you have a solution that uses the tidy language? I'm using dbplyr to talk to a database, and want to do this in one pull instead of separate commands.